# I am struggling to implement Cython with csv module

Tags: python, database, csv, cython, cythonize

primitive programmer here. I have been tasked with cleaning medical data which is stored in csv format.

(please keep in mind while you read this that I am just a beginner programmer so your patience is appreciated)

Some quick background: data1 is a csv that contains the patients required for the study (~17,000 patients). PUF_ED contains emergency department data for MILLIONS of patients. For each patient in data1, I am iterating through PUF_ED until the patient identification key (patient[0]) matches the identification key in PUF_ED (i[0]), and then rewriting the patient data into data2 with the new data from PUF_ED appended to the end.
I understand that pandas would have been vastly more efficient, but due to strict deadline I do not have time to learn pandas and rewrite all of my code. I hope that someone here can help me implement Cython.

```
import csv

def mortWriter():
    puf_ed = open('PUF_ED.csv', 'r')
    ed = csv.reader(puf_ed)
    csv_data1 = open('data1.csv', 'r')
    data1 = csv.reader(csv_data1)
    csv_data2 = open('data2.csv', 'w')
    data2 = csv.writer(csv_data2, 
lineterminator='\n')

    patNum=0
    for patient in data1:
        if patNum==0:
            data2.writerow(patient + ['EDDISP'])
            patNum+=1

        for i in ed:
            if patient[0] == i[0]:
                data2.writerow(patient + [i[12]])
                break

        puf_ed.seek(0)

    puf_ed.close()
    csv_data1.close()
    csv_data2.close()
```

I've tried typing the patient and i variables before the first for loop as integers like so:

```
cdef int patient
cdef int i
```

but I receive the error:
Attempting to index non-array type 'int'

when I try to index them as seen in my code.

What next steps should I take? Thank you so much to anyone who helps me, I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: I doubt that Cython is going to help you much here as you are really reading and writing files to the filesystem more then you are doing anything else. How have you determined Cython is worth the time to implement? Pandas is surprisingly easy to learn, it even loads your CSV files for you and you don't have to mess around writing them or parsing them out as you are doing here which is going to be painful in the extreme for MILLIONS of rows on many many files.

Comment: Why `cython`?  What's wrong with regular python?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, exactly. Get a working python version going first, then, maybe look into speedups like that

Comment: `pandas` isn't usually faster than `numpy`.  But it does have a relatively fast `csv` reader - at least for straightforward cases.  But simple cleanup like this, it be overkill.

Comment: To those asking why cython, it’s because this program will take more than a week to run across all my data. I need it to be faster.

Comment: Is it CPU bound? Besides, you won't really get that much of a speedup if most of your code is relying on regular Python modules such as CSV. You're only saving on the interpreter, but calling the runtime at every step.

Comment: Regarding the actual question, Cython is stating something that's simply true for any language: it doesn't make sense to index an integer. You want arrays there. Or safer analogs like typed memory views: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Answer (score 2):

Before you pull out the "big guns" and write custom cython code or use pandas, I would see if you can improve the algorithm underlying your basic python code first. Looking at your code, your `mortWriter` function are is the following steps (ignoring the `patNum` stuff that does not make sense):

```
for each patient in the study:
    for each patient in the ED:
        if ED patient happens to match study patient:
            do_something()
```

There are a couple of things here that will lead to horrible performance:

1. Finding an object in a list is a linear operation (aka `O(n)`) since you have to search one patient at a time until your find the target patient. You can get dramatically faster, constant-time (aka `O(1)`) lookups using a `set` or a `dict` instead.
2. You should try to avoid repeatedly loading files from disk. This is slow. In terms of speed in general, CPU operations are much faster than memory (RAM) operations, which are much faster than disk/IO operations. Resetting the ED file over and over again and iterating through that is problematic.
3. In general, prefer repeated iterations over smaller rather than bigger lists. In this case, rather than looking through the entire emergency department for each patient in the study, I would invert the process: for each person in the ED, see if they can be found in your smaller study set. This can be combined with point #2 as it is easier to store that smaller study set in memory.

Using all of these points, I came up with the following code:

```
import csv
import math
import numpy as np
import time

def write_random_pat_csv(file_name, max_num_pats, num_data_cols=20, min_id=0, max_id=100_000, prefix="UH"):
    num_pad_zeros = len(str(max_id - 1))
    pat_ids = np.random.randint(min_id, max_id, max_num_pats)
    pat_ids = np.unique(pat_ids)
    num_pats = len(pat_ids)
    pat_ids = [["UH" + str(i).zfill(num_pad_zeros)] for i in pat_ids]
    pat_data = np.random.rand(num_pats, num_data_cols)
    csv_file = open(file_name, "w")
    csv_data = csv.writer(csv_file, lineterminator="\n")
    for i in range(num_pats):
        csv_data.writerow(pat_ids[i] + list(pat_data[i]))
    csv_file.close()

def generate_random_pat_files():
    #num_study_pats = 17_000
    #num_ed_pats = 10_000_000
    num_study_pats = 170
    num_ed_pats = 100000
    write_random_pat_csv("data1.csv", num_study_pats)
    write_random_pat_csv("PUF_ED.csv", num_ed_pats)

def mort_writer_slow():
    puf_ed = open('PUF_ED.csv', 'r')
    ed = csv.reader(puf_ed)
    csv_data1 = open('data1.csv', 'r')
    data1 = csv.reader(csv_data1)
    csv_data2 = open('data2.csv', 'w')
    data2 = csv.writer(csv_data2, lineterminator='\n')

    for patient in data1:
        for i in ed:
            if patient[0] == i[0]:
                data2.writerow(patient + [i[12]])
                break

        puf_ed.seek(0)

    puf_ed.close()
    csv_data1.close()
    csv_data2.close()

def mort_writer_fast():
    puf_ed = open('PUF_ED.csv', 'r')
    csv_data1 = open('data1.csv', 'r')
    csv_data3 = open('data3.csv', 'w')

    ed = csv.reader(puf_ed)
    data1 = csv.reader(csv_data1)
    data3 = csv.writer(csv_data3, lineterminator='\n')

    pat_num = 0
    data1_pat_ids = set([row[0] for row in data1])
    data1_rows = {pat_id: [] for pat_id in data1_pat_ids}
    
    for i in ed:
        pat_id = i[0]
        if pat_id in data1_pat_ids:
            data1_rows[pat_id].append([i[12]])
    
    csv_data1.seek(0)
    for i in data1:
        pat_id = i[0]
        rows = data1_rows[pat_id]
        for row in rows:
            data3.writerow(i + row)

    puf_ed.close()
    csv_data1.close()
    csv_data3.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #pass
    start = time.time()
    generate_random_pat_files()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

    start = time.time()
    mort_writer_slow()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

    start = time.time()
    mort_writer_fast()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

This performs by a factor of 50-100x faster than the original code, at least on the smaller data sets I tried.